# How to trigger onDownloadProgress while installing Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, installation, webstore

I would like to know how to trigger the `onDownloadProgress` event. I made an extension, uploaded it to the Chrome Store and followed every step detailed here: http://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation

Now I'm trying to display a progress bar to users when they install my extension but I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addListener' of undefined
```

this is the code I'm using:

```
chrome.webstore.onDownloadProgress.addListener(function(percentage){
console.log(percentage)
});

chrome.webstore.install('MY_EXTENSION_ID', function(){ console.log('installed') }, function(error){ console.log(error) });
```

It is part of their docs here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webstore
and it's not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like these events were added to Chrome's trunk code [only 5 days ago](https://codereview.chromium.org/175263003/patch/610001/620017). They are available now on [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html), but it will be a while until they are present in the regular Chrome channel.

I don't know why the documentation page is already listing them.

Comment: thanks for confirming that it's not my code's fault :) I'll have to wait then. what bugs me is that it says: "stable since version 15"...for now I'll use: if (chrome.webstore.onDownloadProgress)

Comment: Glad I am not going crazy. I noticed the same thing and the docs said they were available since version 15. It works in Chrome 35 and 36, but not 34.

Comment: The chrome.webstore API has been around since Chrome 15. But until Chrome 35, it only had one function in it: install(). The new calls are correctly marked as "stable since Chrome 35" on the document page. (Of course, it may be that they weren't marked as such when you wrote your comments.)